# Not able to acces service via nodeip:nodeport externally nginx in kubernates

Tags: kubernetes

Hi i have setup a lan connection and setup 10+ cluster nodes and 1 master node i am able to curl nginx server internally but not from external in the lan.

Tutorial followed:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/

Answer (score 0):

How do you try to contact your workers ? via NodePort ?

To contact via NodePort, your servers need to be in the same LAN of you, or directly exposed to internet.

If your on a LAN, you will need to use port-redirection on your ADSL/Router.